# Bibliography messed up by ulem package

Tags: biber, ulem

I needed to use the ulem package to underline sections and subsections, and it works great. The problem is now that the bibliography of my document got messed up.

This is how I have configured it:

```
\usepackage[natbib, backend=biber, sorting=none, doi=false, eprint=false, maxnames=99, firstinits=true, style=numeric-comp, url=false, isbn=false, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{setspace} % reduce space of bibliographic entries

% suppress In: in bibliographic entries
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
```

But since I started using the ulem package I get this type of bibliography:

[image]

How can I solve this? I guess the issue is that biber is using `\emph` to set the journal names in italic. Is there a way to change that formatting?

Comment: `\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}`

Comment: I also found a seemingly exact duplicate

Comment: Yes, it seems it's the same problem.